# How can I get the method body as a text in VS Code extension programmatically?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am attempting to develop a **'V.S. Code Extension'**. The extension will afford the ability, that when you right click on a method's call-signature it will execute the TypeScript code that returns the complete body of method as a string.

For example:

```
int add(int i, int j)  
{  
    return(i+j);  
}
```

This is a C function.

1. right click on function name
2. click on custom menu option

then it should return complete function as a string.

Comment: parse the file to find the `{...}` content, start at the location of the context click

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you asking about when the name is right-clicked in the function definition, or anywhere it occurs in the program?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 yes, I'm asking about when the function name is right clicked in the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider` command, you can gather all functions from a file. With that in hands, you check if the current position is in one of the functions.

Something like this to retrieve the functions:

```
const symbolsToFind = [SymbolKind.Function, SymbolKind.Method, SymbolKind.Constructor];

    const docSymbols = await commands.executeCommand(
        'vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider',
        window.activeTextEditor.document.uri
    ) as DocumentSymbol[];

    const docSymbolsFunctionsMethods = docSymbols
        ? docSymbols.filter(symbol => symbolsToFind.includes(symbol.kind))
        : undefined;
```

Each Symbol provides you with a Range, which defines the start and end of the function declaration and body. You will probably need to parse the *current line* to validate if the cursor is positioned in function's call signature, as you described.

Be aware that you will probably need a recursive approach (each Symbol can contain other Symbols). A more complete sample is available on my Separators extension (https://github.com/alefragnani/vscode-separators/blob/b6d515847bbaccf6395b24f9fdf82c373cb24fd7/src/symbols.ts#L51)

Hope this helps